# Flag to Migrate Declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Why was **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25532581/1536038)** question declined, see screenshot

[image]

Comment: The question had an accepted answer by the time you flagged it, why did it need to be migrated?

Comment: @bluefeet So that it serves a purpose on Web Application

Answer (score 10):

The question isn't off topic on SO.  Questions are only migrated if they are quality on topic questions on the target site *and are not on topic on the site they are currently on*.

Comment: Have to read the tag wiki text?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra The tag wiki says _if you have issues with the web application, your question would be more suitable at Web Applications Stack Exchange would be more suitable at Web Applications Stack Exchange_, this question isn't about the application.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra So far none of the readers of the question have felt that it is off topic where it is, it has been answered, and it definitely looks like a programming question to me.  While a good many questions around that site are likely not programming related, clearly the readers of this question felt that this one was.  You seem to be applying a set of rules without actually thinking about the context of the question at hand.

Comment: This is just a convoluted formula and it has nothing to do with programming. All takes place in a web application of which Web Application should accept questions too.

Comment: @bluefeet good point, however it happens to be an integral part of the web application

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra This question may well be on topic on Web Applications.  I have no idea.  That is irrelevant to this discussion.  The question is on topic on Stack Overflow, at least in the eyes of all other people that have looked at it thus far.

Comment: The same reason that all excel questions are on-topic here and should belong to Super User? I would say protectionism.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I didn't say every single Excel question was on topic on SO, just this one.  It's possible to have *some* Excel questions be on topic without having *every* Excel question on topic.

Comment: Resumé: this is just your ordinary type of Google Spreadsheet question fit for Web Applications. I'm here to advocate for that.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra And I'm saying it's irrelevant whether or not it's fit for web applications.  I've said that several times.  It needs to be off topic on SO to be migrated.

Comment: @pnuts Three people had actively told him it shouldn't be migrated, someone answered it, clearly feeling that it was an appropriate question, that makes quite a few people.  You even looked at the question, commented on it, clearly evaluated it to some degree, and yet didn't see the need to vote to close it as off topic.  It's not like the question just didn't get any attention at all.

Comment: @pnuts The moderator responding to the flag, me, and bluefeet were the three people I was referring to.

Comment: @pnuts *Most* questions about the application are probably going to be off topic, as most of them aren't really going to be programming problems.  This one happens to be an exception, as it is conceptually a programming problem.  That it's programming within the scope of a web application doesn't magically make it not programming.

Answer (score 4):

From [Respect the community -- your own, and others'](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/):

> **Respecting your own community**
>
> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to *that* community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn’t be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

In this case, the question is on topic on Web Applications. However, the asker chose to ask it on Stack Overflow, where the question is also on-topic.

Many Stack Exchange sites do have slight overlap with each other, and that's okay because it gives askers a bit more flexibility in those cases where it's not immediately clear where a question would fit.

In this case, the criteria for evaluating a question is clear:  *In order to be a candidate for migration to another site, the question must first be deemed off-topic on the original site.*  If you think it's off-topic, vote to close. If it gets closed, then you're more likely to make a stronger case for migration. However, as [Servy says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270471/552792), as long as it's also on topic on Stack Overflow, it is not a candidate for migration.

The same guidelines would apply if the asker asked this on Web Applications and someone thought it was a programming question. We wouldn't migrate it away from the original site unless it's off-topic on that site. Hope this helps.

Comment: @pnuts It means if you need help just navigating the web application, then you are clearly in the wrong spot here. If your question is about coding involving the web application in some way, then it can fit here if it meets our other criteria. That's my imperfect opinion on it, and that does make sense when you think about it. The question in question is about programming using the web application in some way... Which is in our scope.

Comment: @pnuts While I'm not sure how well that one would go over, I suppose that's one way of looking at it. Probably more along the lines of "If you want to programmatically use/open MS Word, we're your people. If you want to just use MS Word for typing and formatting letters, you might want to check elsewhere." I would say.